# How to get subtotal price on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models, User and Voucher.

User has_many Vouchers
Voucher belongs_to user

In my schema:

```
create_table "vouchers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "price"
    t.float "quantity"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_pakets_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "id_number"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

In my route:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :vouchers
  end
```

In user controller:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @vouchers = Voucher.all
  end
```

In voucher model:

```
def subtotal
  price * quantity
end
```

In my user index:

```
<% @users.each.with_index(1) do |user| %>
 <%= user.username %>
 <%= user.vouchers.count %>
 <%= user.vouchers.subtotal %> (how to get this subtotal?)
<% end %>
```

I got this error => "undefined method `subtotal' for "

Please help me and thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User model, you can define a function to sum all of the voucher subtotals:

```
def vouchers_subtotal
  sum = 0
  vouchers.each {|v|
    sum += v.subtotal
  }
  return sum
end
```

Another option is to just sum all of the values in the template file:

```
<%= user.vouchers.collect{|v| v.subtotal}.inject(:+) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `subtotal` method in the User model, so you should call `user.subtotal`, but `price` and `quantity` are defined in the Voucher class, so I guess what you really want to do is to define the `subtotal` method on the Voucher model.

And then maybe add another method to the User model that sums all subtotals of vouchers belonging to that User, something like:

```
def subtotals_sum
  vouchers.sum(&:subtotal)
end
```

You can check the docs for the `sum` method here https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

Comment: can you give me an example how to add another method to the User model that sums all subtotals of vouchers belonging to that User ? thank you.

Comment: @Garbela I've just updated the answer to include that method